# How do you define a command to select nested groups?

Tags: macros, tex-core, expansion, grouping, data-structures

Assuming a pair structure (2-tuple) is defined using groups

```
{{<tokens1>}{<tokens2>}}
```

is it possible to define a command `\first#1{...}` (and `\last#1{...}`) taking the surrounding group as its single argument which expands to `<tokens1>` but *consumes* `{<tokens2>}` (and vice versa)? If so, how?

> By *consume* I mean expanding to `\relax` or the empty token list (or whatever is the most appropriate pattern for *expand to nothing*).
>
> This is for a LISP style recursive list implementation.
>
> TeX-core solutions preferred.

Comment: `\def\first#1{\@firstoftwo#1}`?

Comment: Note that expanding to `\relax`, and empty group or disappearing entirely are different things!

Comment: In general, the typical list implementation in TeX looks something like `\do@item{<tokens1>}\do@item{<tokens2>}`

Comment: Also, a pair would typically look like `\do@pair{<tokens1>}{<tokens2>}`

Comment: Note that a LISP list is also constructed from a binary operator, see [S-expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expressions).

Comment: @Manuel Would have guessed that there is some LaTeX command but I'd prefer some low level TeX code.

Comment: @FK82 If that command works (which I'm not sure, see Joseph's comment and also Stephan's) then just copying the definition from `latex.ltx` and then you have some low level :)

Comment: @Manuel It works under the provision that the first argument is either passed directly (e.g. `\first{{a}{b}}`) or an `\expandafter` is prefixed in case of a token (e.g. `\expandafter\first\pair`; where `\pair` is defined as `\def\pair#1#2{{{#1}{#2}}}`).

Comment: @FK82 `\long\def\@firstoftwo#1#2{#1}` is what LaTeX does, so it can be easily added to your macros.

Comment: @StephanLehmke Ok. I'm not sure what you're trying to say, really.

Comment: @FK82 Of course you're free to construct lists any way you want. Experience suggests though that it'll be easiest when either following the TeX or the LISP convention ;-)

Comment: @egreg Yeah, actually this was the first solution I came up with. But I don't think it's a good idea to create an otherwise redundant command just for this particular issue. Is there any way to do this (e.g. I've tried to do expand the outer group and then work with `\aftergroup` -- to split the groups up -- but it didn't work).

Comment: @FK82 There is *no* group involved when TeX absorbs an argument to a macro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
%!TEX TS-program = pdftex

\catcode`@=11
\long\def\@firstoftwo#1#2{#1}
\long\def\@secondoftwo#1#2{#2}
\def\first#1{\@firstoftwo#1}
\def\last#1{\@secondoftwo#1}
\catcode`@=12

\first{{+tokens1+}{--tokens2--}}

\last{{+tokens1+}{--tokens2--}}

\bye
```

[image]

Of course, if you don't have (or want) anything to do with LaTeX. There's no need for `\@firstoftwo` while `\firstoftwo` would be useful anyways.